# Meta Tag Generation and Verification on Remote Sites with PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a project where I need to verify user website ownership. As verification of ownership with meta tags is one of the most practiced ways, so I'm thinking to implement this in my project. As of now, the idea is to generate unique ids with `uniq()` function of PHP. I have two questions to be answered:

1. Is this (`uniq()` function) the best way to go?
2. What's the best way to read and verify this meta tag when placed on a remote website?

I hope I'm not violating SO rules by asking a pretty lengthier question. Waiting for some expert help.

Comment: There are no real SO rules, especially in terms of length ... and this is not a "pretty lengthy" question. Don't worry!

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan :) Waiting for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <meta name="blah-blah-blah" content="can be any junk" />
```

Tell them to place that on their site and give you the URL, obtain contents of that URL and look for that very meta tag and content, Job Done!

You don't have to get really fancy about it and use `uniq()` or the `best possible ways etc`, it's just a URL verification.

To answer your question number 2, PHP provides you a simple way to read meta tags

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');
if($tags["blah-blah-blah"]=="can be any junk")
   echo "site is verified";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hanky, it produced the results I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

1. As for generating a random string to would probably be better off using a a function similar to `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))`
2. You can use PHP's `get_meta_tags('http://example.com')` to generate an array of meta tags for a particular webpage. Then loop through the array and make sure your key is set and the values match.

More information on PHP's `get_meta_tags` can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: Thanks James, for your answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Is this (uniq() function) the best way to go?

Doing it that way is definetly ok. One drawback I see is that you have to store the unique id (e.g. in a database table) assigned to each website.

This step can be avoided if you use a hash function and some secret salt value.

```
<?php
define('SECRET','j83h93hbbf84zufhh348h4'); // some random string, keep secret

function generateSiteId($domain) {
    return sha1($domain . SECRET);
}

function verifyDomainId($domain, $idToTest) {
    return (generateSiteId($domain) == $idToTest);
}
```

Send the user generateSiteId('www.example.com') and test your value from the meta tag with verifyDomainId('www.example.com','whatEverMetaTagValueFound').

This way you dont even have to remember the site specific unique id and this approach is secure als long as you keep SECRET secret ;-)

Comment: Thanks, BTW the site heavily depends on MySQL so storing the meta tags for different sites in database doesn't make any big difference.

Comment: Why is all the secrecy required for such a public thing; what benefit does it provide?

Comment: As the whole procedure is about proofing ownership of a certain domain, at least some kind of secure value should be used for authentication via meta tags. If we would not have this requirement then we could completely skip this whole process or use a standard value for each and every website. So if we want to keep the proof of ownership than we should use some kind of security and in such cases I would always opt for a strong security mechanism.

Comment: Why does proof of ownership require something *secure*? In this method the only requirement of proof of ownership is the fact that the meta tag you gave them is in fact placed on that website and that's it. Why would any security be required here? The only consideration is that the tag value pair you give to that person should not be something that can be found on generally every website. So if you check for a tag `testing12345-ownership-test` with a value of `1` that is as secure as checking for `xasascas324dsadada@!#!!@#@!##` with a value of `#$%#$%#$%#$@%$%@%$@$%$#%$#@%$%$@`, isn't that so?

Comment: If we can agree that some kind(!) of site specific information should be used for proof of ownership then I can see no argument in favor of an unsecure solution. It's not complicated, it's not costly, so why not use something secure?